# How to add a new language mode into Ace text editor?

Tags: r, shiny, ace-editor

I'd like to use the Ace editor in a Shiny Application but first need to specify the grammar for a new language, a not so widely used statistical programming language for mixed effects modeling that is not currently a supported "mode" in Ace.

I know that tmlanguage files can be imported into traditional Ace Editor, is this the best approach, i.e. define grammar for new language in tmlanguage file? And do you know if Shiny Ace (Ace editor that integrates into R Shiny applications https://github.com/trestletech/shinyAce) also supports tmlanguage file integration to support new modes?  I've looked quite extensively about how to do this but haven't found a solution.

Any guidance or suggestions are greatly appreciated.